# Tracing the existing curve with star symbol

Tags: plotting, mesh, marker

```
b1={1.8743,1.8784,1.88248,1.89049,1.89828,1.90587,1.91327,1.96335,2.03035,2.12536,2.23701,2.30098,2.34255,2.37175,2.3934,2.42334,2.44307,2.48725,2.51208,2.5173,2.52799,2.53164,2.53348,2.53533,2.53625,2.53745,2.53793,2.53894,2.53909,2.53543};
ks1={0.01,1.,2.,4.,6.,8.,10.,25.,50.,100.,200.,300.,400.,500.,600.,800.,1000.,2000.,4000.,5000.,10000.,15000.,20000.,30000.,40000.,70000.,100000.,1.*10^6,1.*10^8,1.*10^12};
data1 = Transpose[{ks1, b1}];
s1 = ListLogLinearPlot[data1, Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, AxesStyle -> Black, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

How to put star symbol on same plot which traces the curve. I know with the Plot marker we can achive this, but the thing is I want the tracing at equidistance from start to end. With my data points, I am not getting the tracing properly. How to achive this.

Comment: "I want the tracing at equidistance from start to end." - you did quite a bit of a jump here. You have data points, but placing a star at each of these data points is not what you want? What exactly do you mean by "equidistance", distance along the curve that interpolates your data points?

Comment: I mean I want to trace the curve which is formed by a data points, between the data the line is traced. now all I have is a line. I want to place star from start to end with   placement being at an equal distance

Comment: I meant to say just treat the curve as a contious curve and I  wanted to mark the star from start to end

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124717)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can use the *undocumented* `MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}` option setting to place equispaced (by the arclength of the interpolating curve) markers:

```
Normal[ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ks1, b1}], Joined -> True, 
                         Mesh -> 6, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, MeshStyle -> Red, 
                         PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}]] /. 
Point[pt_] :> Inset[Style["\[FivePointedStar]", Large], pt]
```

[image: equispaced markers]

Comment: Can we make the star unfilled with colour

Comment: Yes, just replace `"\[FivePointedStar]"` with `"☆"`. Or, take your pick among the symbols listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(glyph)).

Comment: Hm. I cannot help but to me, this does not look equidistantly spaced with respect to arclength...

Comment: @Henrik, I will try to investigate tomorrow, as I have just borrowed a friend's computer to write some answers (and check on you guys ;)), and I have to go back home. The problem is that it's not immediately clear how `ListLogLinearPlot[]` is interpolating the points (and it wasn't the cubic interpolant when I did a check before posting).

Answer (score 9):

As [Henrik Schumacher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/38178/henrik-schumacher) correctly [points out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/188874/tracing-the-existing-curve-with-star-symbol#comment492389_188875) in the comments, the stars on the plot produced by the [naive application](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/188875/280) of the undocumented `MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}` option

> do not look equidistantly spaced with respect to arclength

It took me a while to figure out what happens. The reason is that scales in the vertical and horizontal directions of the plot differ by an order of magnitude. I tried other plotting functions like `ListPlot`, `Plot`, `ParametricPlot` and found that all of them also suffer from this issue.

The following approach solves the problem *exactly*.

We start by defining our `data1`:

```
b1={1.8743,1.8784,1.88248,1.89049,1.89828,1.90587,1.91327,1.96335,2.03035,2.12536,2.23701,2.30098,2.34255,2.37175,2.3934,2.42334,2.44307,2.48725,2.51208,2.5173,2.52799,2.53164,2.53348,2.53533,2.53625,2.53745,2.53793,2.53894,2.53909,2.53543};
ks1={0.01,1.,2.,4.,6.,8.,10.,25.,50.,100.,200.,300.,400.,500.,600.,800.,1000.,2000.,4000.,5000.,10000.,15000.,20000.,30000.,40000.,70000.,100000.,1.*10^6,1.*10^8,1.*10^12};
data1 = Transpose[{ks1, b1}];
```

Now define future `AspectRatio` of the plotting area (the option `AspectRatio` [determines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83810/280) the actual aspect ratio of the plotting area with `PlotRangePadding` included):

```
aspectRatio = 1./GoldenRatio;
```

The `Graphics` produced by `ListLogLinearPlot` contains log-transformed data plotted in the usual linear cordinate system (it is just `Ticks` what creates the illusion of a logarithmic coordinate system):

```
data1Log = {Log@#1, #2} & @@@ data1;
dataRange = MinMax /@ Transpose[data1Log];
```

Now create rescaling function and its inverse:

```
t = RescalingTransform[
   MinMax /@ Transpose[data1Log], {{0, 1}, {0, aspectRatio}}];
tInv = InverseFunction[t];
```

This function makes vertical and horizontal scales equal in `Graphics`.

Then we use `MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}` for generating the equidistantly spaced points with respect to arclength:

```
s2 = ListLinePlot[t[data1Log], PlotRange -> All, 
   MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}, Mesh -> True];
```

Extracting the equidistant points and performing the inverse coordinate transform:

```
pts = tInv @@@ Cases[Normal[s2], _Point, -1];
```

Now we can use these coordinates for placing the star glyphs in `Epilog`:

```
Show[ListLogLinearPlot[data1, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, 
  AxesStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog -> {Red, Translate[Inset[Style["☆", 15, Bold], {0, 0}], pts]}, 
  AspectRatio -> aspectRatio], PlotRange -> dataRange, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

> [image: plot]

Note however that [*Mathematica* can't guarantee](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2214/280) exact positioning for the font glyphs on the plot. [`ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PolygonMarker) guarantees exact positioning of the markers:

```
Show[ListLogLinearPlot[data1, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, 
  AxesStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog -> {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Red], 
    ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"]["FivePointedStar", Offset[5], pts]}, 
  AspectRatio -> aspectRatio], PlotRange -> dataRange, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]
```

> [image: plot]

Voila! :)

---

**UPDATE**: I just accidentally found that I [knew](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/64345/280) about `MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}` already several years ago but completely forgot due to non-use of this functionality. I can add to that old post that now we have the wonderful [`GraphicsInformation`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138907/280) function by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll) which simplifies things considerably.

Comment: Very nice! ${}$